# No spot of light on cube

Tags: opengl

I have made three sources of light and one cube

I don't see a spot of light on faces. It's look like entire polygon is lit.
And i don't know is this posible and cube need more polygons or mayby light settings are bad.
Settings i use.

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 150.0f);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 15.0f);
```

Comment: Have you done `glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );`? Also, is there any more relevant code that you can supply?

Comment: Try with something else than a cube - a sphere or a [teapot](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glutSolidTeapot.3GLUT.html). You will hardly see any per-vertex lightning on a cube with only 8 verticles. See [#2 here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that the fixed-function lighting equation is only evaluated at the vertices of a triangle and interpolated across the fragment.  No per-pixel lighting unless you get creative with `GL_DOT3_RGB` textures.

Therefore if you want to see a nice spotlight highlight on your cube you'll need to subdivide your cube faces so that they're closer to pixel-sized:

[image: Subdivision Example]

EDIT: Also remember to pass in reasonable per-vertex normals.  Lighting doesn't work too well without them :)

Comment: See [OpenGL common pitfalls: 2. Poor Tessellation Hurts Lighting:](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/)